# Adding mdb geodatabase layer (feature class) to QGIS project using python?

Tags: pyqgis, personal-geodatabase

I want to add a feature class of a personal geodatabase mdb to my qgs project by code (a plugin I am working on).

I am using a command similar to that used for adding shapefiles, but this is not working.
I guess there must be a way, since it is possible to add the layer using the Add Vector Layer button.

This is the code i am using on the Python console:

```
mylayer = QgsVectorLayer("D:\Test\test.mdb\points", "mypoints", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mylayer)
```

The first line runs without error but the second one does not produce any result, contrary to the result is I do a similar command using a shapefile.

I am using QGIS 2.2 Valmiera 32 bits on Windows 7 64 bits. I did a previous research but I did not find any results!!! The feature class is not inside a feature dataset.

---

I guess I would have to use a QgsDataSourceURI(), but i can not figure out the syntax. I have been trying. Also, I would also want to add that migrating the mdb is not an option, I have requested this before but my superiors have refused. And this geodatabase (points) is updated daily and huge. My goal after loading is clipping it based on a zone of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Well is was easier than expected, not ODBC stuff, just the following code:

```
mylayer = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\Test\test.mdb|layername=points", "mypoints", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mylayer)
```

I hope it will work on the newer versions of QGis.

Comment: QgsMapLayerRegistry doesn't work on v3.x, probably just replace with QgsProject.instance().addMayLayer()